# В зависимости от выбранного radio меняется href в button

Tags: backbutton, javascript

Есть button `<button class="btn-primary" onclick="location.href='/index/3?step2'">`

и 2 input - допустим `<input  id="1"  type="radio" />` и `<input  id="2"  type="radio" />`

нужно, чтобы при клике на input id=1 ссылка в button становилась `/index/3?step2-1`, а при клике на input id=2 становилась `/index/3?step2-2`

Comment: Использовать button и onclick не самая лучшая идея. Используйте form и js меняйте атрибут action. Если такой вариант приемлим, то можгу накидать как вам пример.

Comment: Покопался в коде формы, и оказалось, что ссылку можно упрятать в action="/index/3?step2"

можете что-нибудь посоветовать? заранее благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из самых простых вариантов. Однако логику лучше выделить в отдельный js файл или как в предыдущем ответе.

```
<form id="myFrom" action="">
<input type="radio" name="same" id="radio1" onChange="this.form.action='/index/3?step2-1' ">
<input type="radio" name="same" id="radio2" onChange="this.form.action='/index/3?step2-2' ">
<button class="btn-primary">Click me</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>My File</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                // Выбираем все кнопки и добавляем обработчик
                var buttons = document.getElementsByName("step");
                var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
                for (var i in buttons) {
                    if (!buttons[i].value) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
                        form.action = this.value;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="step" value="/index/3?step2" checked="checked"/> Стандартно
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="step" value="/index/3?step2-1"/> Шаг1
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="step" value="/index/3?step2-2"/> Шаг2
        </label>
        <form action="/index/3?step2" id="myForm">
            <button type="submit">Отправить на</button>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: не обижайтесь, но последний ответ компактнее)